# AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslib._TSObject' has no attribute' _reduce_cython_'

Tags: python-3.6, pyinstaller

I have a created a tkinter app for Convolution neural network to identify images. I am trying to compile the py file with pyinstaller but i am receiving this error:

AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslib._TSObject' has no attribute' _reduce_cython_'

i have also attached the screenshot of the error [image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas myScript.py
```

and it is working now

Answer (score 9):

Just re-start in case you are using Jupyter notebook. It worked for me. Also make sure, you are working in correct python environment.

Comment: Although this answer might not work for everyone, it did work for me. Restarted the kernel and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This problem just happened to me when i try to create an app of an uncompleted project for testing purpose.

I have pandas imported, but i didnt call it in my script.

Removing the import line or call pandas was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have cython too,

1. `pip install cython` or `conda install cython`
2. `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas program.py`

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions did not work for me but what did is:

1. add `import pandas` at the very top of `conftest.py`
2. add `ignore:numpy\.ufunc size changed.+:RuntimeWarning` to the `filterwarnings` option of `pytest.ini`
3. upgraded freezegun to the latest version